# 2 domain pointing to single website with different meta description and title in SERP

Tags: seo, search-results

Let's say I have one website `abc.com.my`, and now I want to create a new domain `xyz.my` but with its own meta description and meta title which points to `abc.com.my`. So I need to create one `index.html` inside the `xyz.my` domain then redirect to `abc.com.my`.

So in SERP I hope to see `xyz.my` with its own meta description and meta title and `abc.com.my` with a different meta description and title but both point to `abc.com.my`. So will this affect my ranking or is it bad for SEO?

[image: expected search results]

Comment: Just curious how you propose to generate a new title and meta description when accessing the site via `xyx.my` when you are **redirecting** to another domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is a little bit illogical and totally useless for SEO. If you do this, you'll see on Google Search only your old domain and it won't affect its SEO on anyway.

You need to understand that if you redirect one domain to another, the redirected domain won't show up on Google Search because the redirect says to search engines your old domain has been migrated to a new domain.